# merge value of json data

Tags: json, filter, lodash

i have an reactjs application and i need filter data with a json, according the timestamp, i've had filtered the date by years and then by month, now i need to sum its values into the months. i tried with lodash some functions but with success

this is my json file now

```
'2016':{
  'jan':{
    '0':{
        'measures':{
        'step':{
          'text': 'step',
          'unit': 123
        },
        'calories':{
          'text': 'cal',
          'unit': 321
        }
      }
    },
    '1':{
      'measures':{
        'step':{
          'text': 'step',
          'unit': 45
        },
        'calories':{
          'text': 'cal',
          'unit': 65
        }
      }
    }
  },
  'feb':{
    '0':{
        'measures':{
        'step':{
          'text': 'step',
          'unit': 98
        },
        'calories':{
          'text': 'cal',
          'unit': 78
        }
      }
    },
    '1':{
      'measures':{
        'step':{
          'text': 'step',
          'unit': 21
        },
        'calories':{
          'text': 'cal',
          'unit': 41
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and i want this

```
'2016':{
  'jan':{
    'measures':{
      'step':{
        'text': 'step',
        'unit': 168 // sum value of measures
      },
      'calories':{
        'text': 'cal',
        'unit': 386
      }
     }
  },
  'feb':{
    'measures':{
      'step':{
        'text': 'step',
        'unit': 119
      },
      'calories':{
        'text': 'cal',
        'unit': 139
      }
    }
  }
}
```

any idea? 
is there are any plugin or component on reactjs that will be usefull as well
thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) for the traversing all years and months. Use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to obtain all `measures` from maps, [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) to set the sum for each measure types and then [thru()](https://lodash.com/docs#thru) to return the `measures` object signature.

```
var result = _.mapValues(years, months => {
  return _.mapValues(months, month => {
    return _.chain(month)
      .map()
      .map('measures')
      .reduce((measures, measureTypes) => {
        return _.reduce(measureTypes, (result, measureType, type) => {
          if (result[type]) {
            result[type].unit += measureType.unit;
          } else {
            result[type] = measureType;
          }
          return result;
        }, measures);
      }, {})
      .thru(measures => ({ measures }))
      .value();
  });
});
```

```js
var years = {
  '2016': {
    'jan': {
      '0': {
        'measures': {
          'step': {
            'text': 'step',
            'unit': 123
          },
          'calories': {
            'text': 'cal',
            'unit': 321
          }
        }
      },
      '1': {
        'measures': {
          'step': {
            'text': 'step',
            'unit': 45
          },
          'calories': {
            'text': 'cal',
            'unit': 65
          }
        }
      }
    },
    'feb': {
      '0': {
        'measures': {
          'step': {
            'text': 'step',
            'unit': 98
          },
          'calories': {
            'text': 'cal',
            'unit': 78
          }
        }
      },
      '1': {
        'measures': {
          'step': {
            'text': 'step',
            'unit': 21
          },
          'calories': {
            'text': 'cal',
            'unit': 41
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var result = _.mapValues(years, months => {
  return _.mapValues(months, month => {
    return _.chain(month)
      .map()
      .map('measures')
      .reduce((measures, measureTypes) => {
        return _.reduce(measureTypes, (result, measureType, type) => {
          if (result[type]) {
            result[type].unit += measureType.unit;
          } else {
            result[type] = measureType;
          }
          return result;
        }, measures);
      }, {})
      .thru(measures => ({ measures }))
      .value();
  });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, thats was very usefull, but wat if i have a diferent json structure how [link](https://jsfiddle.net/juanX/prtnezm4/) filtering per month doing the same , following the timestamp, i can to do the same logic for this case? again thanks a lot

Comment: Are the timestamps the same for all `measures`? if not then I'm not entirely sure what the result should be? You should probably provide the resulting values after the transformation as well.

Comment: ok get it, i've used the first one with another json with more values, and is working using groupBy from lodash for this case